# How to make a POST request with Angular HttpClient?

Tags: angular, post

Help please make a POST request in Angular. I created a model from the name, price, description fields that I want to send. I also use reactive forms with little validation. Also, I have a service with which I want to post the method of sending data, and the method that will send the laptop to the database - `sendLaptopToDatabase` How can I make a post request?

laptopService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {Laptop} from "../models/laptop";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LaptopService {

private url = `http://localhost:8081/laptop`

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

sendLaptop(laptop: Laptop):Observable<Laptop> {
return this.httpClient.post<Laptop>(this.url, laptop)
   }

}
```

create-laptop.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
     selector: 'app-create-laptop',
     templateUrl: './create-laptop.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./create-laptop.component.css']
})

export class CreateLaptopComponent implements OnInit {

name = new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
   Validators.minLength(5),
   Validators.maxLength(25)])
price = new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
   Validators.minLength(5),
   Validators.maxLength(30)])
description = new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
   Validators.minLength(5),
   Validators.maxLength(95)])

loginForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
   name: this.name,
   price: this.price,
   description: this.description })

   constructor() { }
   ngOnInit(): void {}
   sendLaptopToDatabase() {}
}
```

create-laptop.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="sendLaptopToDatabase()">
<div><input type="text" [formControl]="name"></div>
<div><input type="text" [formControl]="price"></div>
<div><input type="text" [formControl]="description"></div>
<button [disabled]="loginForm.invalid">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

laptop.ts

```
export interface Laptop {
name: string;
price: number;
description: string; }
```

Comment: Remember that to "execute" an observable you need subscribe to it (or using pipe async in html)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call your API by doing a post request by following these steps:

1. Inject the `LaptopService` into the component `CreateLaptopComponent` constructor like this `constructor(laptopService: LaptopService)`
2. Add this code in the `sendLaptopToDatabase()` in your component

   ```
   this.laptopService.sendLaptop(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(laptop => {console.log(laptop});
   ```

Instead of the console.log() you can handle the response as you want.